# How can I instantiate enemies in a 2D game at a set Viewport Position before my camera enters the room? (Or alternative solution!)

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, viewport, instantiation

I'm currently working on a 2D game where I'm trying to pre-populate my level with encounters, I want the enemies already in the room when the player enters. Right now the encounter is triggered upon entering the room when the camera bumps into the collider and the enemies are instantiated at the Viewport position, however because it does it while the camera is moving into the room the position is incorrect. Using hard values isn't an option because the maps could of course change and also I may want them randomly generated at some point. So I guess ultimately the problem is the camera not being in the right position when they instantiate and not wanting enemies to "pop" in once it is.

Edit: To clarify, when I just move the camera to the rooms without the collider and instantiate manually the enemies appear in the right position in the rooms, this is basically what I want but BEFORE the camera hits the room so the enemies aren't "teleporting" in.

Is there a way I can I instantiate an enemy at the same point on the screen regardless of resolution in each specific room at the start of the level?

Encounters will have up to 3 enemies and they will always hold the same formation (with spots randomized to add diversity)

Here is my instantiating code:

```
 [SerializeField] public List<GameObject> levelEnemies = new List<GameObject>();
 GameObject levelEnemy;
 Vector3 enemyPosition;
 Vector3 viewportPosition = new Vector3(0.8f, 0.5f, 10f); // Place on the screen I decided I want single enemies to appear
 Camera cam;

 void Start()
 {

     Debug.Log("Enemy Triggered");
     cam = Camera.main;
     enemyPosition = cam.ViewportToWorldPoint(viewportPosition);
     levelEnemy = Instantiate(levelEnemies[0], enemyPosition, Quaternion.identity); //instantiate test enemy at the converted position

     //navigation.DisableNavigation();
 }
```

Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated or a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use a spawn gameobject that you place in the room to spawn your enemyies. On awake you instantiate them so there should be no problem of them being spawned on view or on the wrong position.

Comment: But how do I go about ensuring they spawn in the same predetermine spots regardless of where the room is? For example, right now if I set the enemies to spawn at 1, 1, in a room at 1,1, they would still spawn at 1,1 if the room was at 2,2.

Comment: so you could do an instantiate relative to the position of the room plus an offset. now you could go different ways: 1 manually place the spawner in the room and instantiate relative to the spawner position, 2 add the spawner as a prefab to the room so it will move or be created with it. I hope you get the idea. In general i would avoid to hard code the position in because then if you change idea you will need to go in the script and change it manually

Answer (score 0):

Few (alternative) solutions I would suggest would be:

1. Placing special type of objects in the scene that are connected to trigger and spawn enemies on their position while trigger is hit (as other user suggested)
2. Placing Enemies as part of level-design, but setting them as inactive, then using trigger only to call on them SetActive(true) (simpler and quicker in terms of performance implementation of idea in point 1)
3. Spawn enemies at positions relative to the player instead of camera

4.Make spawn position relative to trigger itself

Try to implement it in the way that works without this randomness and add randomness later, when you will know what type range of random outcomes satisfy you.
To prevent problems from maps changing use one of two solutions:

1. Use serializable ( https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html ) (you really should use them a lot if you don't already)
2. Connect those points to some gameobjects (again probably via serialization)

I hope it solves your problem